# react-native navigation error : ScreenContainer is not attached under ReactRootView

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

So I have a `<NavigationContainer>` with a `<TabNav.Screen name='home' component={Map}...` at the head of my `app.js`.
One tab is a mapview. But I want to have another navigation (Detail, edit, report) into the modal of a marker of the map with something like this :

```
<View style={styles.footer} collapsable={false}>
                <NavigationContainer independent={true}>
                    <Stack.Navigator
                        screenOptions={{
                            presentation: "modal",
                            headerShown: false,
                            gestureEnabled: true,
                            cardOverlayEnabled: true,
                            ...TransitionPresets.ModalPresentationIOS,
                        }}>
                        {props.infos.rights && (
                            <Stack.Screen name="Modifier" component={Modification} initialParams={props.infos.BarInfos} />
                        )}
                        <Stack.Screen name="Signaler" component={ReportBar} initialParams={props.infos.BarInfos} />

                    </Stack.Navigator>
                </NavigationContainer>
            </View>
```

And I am facing this error all the time:

[image]

What's a ReactRootView exactly ?
What can I do ?

Comment: It's incorrect.. You can't wrap <NavigationContainer> inside a View.. You need to define it in App.js something like this https://snack.expo.dev/@vedexpo/brave-carrot

Comment: ok but I dont want neither the modal neither the 'edit' or 'report' page to be shown at the root of the app, how can I do ?

Comment: made a new post with all the code - > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72757521/react-native-navigation-how-to-set-up-a-stack-navigation-in-a-child-modal