# react-native: how can I do a navigation somewhere in a modal

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have this in `app.js`

```
<NavigationContainer>
<TabNav.Navigator initialRouteName='home'>
<TabNav.Screen name='home' component={Map} options={{
            tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
              <MaterialCommunityIcons name="map-search-outline" color={color} size={30} style={style.iconStyle} />
            ),
            tabBarLabel: (null)
          }} />
          <TabNav.Screen name='user' component={User} options={{
            tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
              <MaterialCommunityIcons name="card-account-details-outline" color={color} size={30} style={style.iconStyle} />
            ),
tabBarLabel: (null)
          }} />

          <TabNav.Screen name='settings' component={Settings} options={{
            tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
              <MaterialCommunityIcons name="set-square" color={color} size={30} style={style.iconStyle} />
            ),
            tabBarLabel: (null)
          }} />
        </TabNav.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
```

In the component `Map` with the `MapView` there is markers showing modals with informations.
How can I go into new form screens component `edit` and `report` from that modal ?
Navigation stack doesn't work from there, or I am missing something ?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do it by passing props.

```
<Component navigation={this.props.navigation} />
```

Inside Component

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('NextScreen')
```

Comment: Check this other post I wrote:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72713016/react-native-navigation-error-screencontainer-is-not-attached-under-reactrootv
Not possible like that ?

Comment: I think I am getting it, but it means I have to make a hidden stack nav as children of the tabnav to get it everywhere I need by passing the nav props ?
Btw does const navigation=useNavigation() can replace all the nav props use?

Comment: made a new post with all the code - > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72757521/react-native-navigation-how-to-set-up-a-stack-navigation-in-a-child-modal